# Using GeoJSON Services in Arcade Expression

Tags: gis, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to use an Arcade expression with GeoJSON services in a map using the ArcGIS Javascript API. The intent of the Arcade expression is to return a count of lakes that intersect a county that the user clicks on. Both the lakes and county polygons being GeoJSON services. Swapping out the lakes GeoJSON service with a ArcGIS Feature Layer service results in the expression functioning properly, returning the count of lakes that intersect the county GeoJSON service.

```
  var template = {
  title: "{LABEL}",
  content: "{expression/countyInfo}",
  expressionInfos: [
  {
    name: "countyInfo",
    title: "Marker Info",
    expression: `

    var lake = FeatureSetByName($map, 'Lakes');

    var lakeIntersect = Intersects(lake, $feature);

    var cnt = Count(lakeIntersect);

    return \` 
    Number of lakes: \${Text(cnt, "####")}   
    \`
    `
  }
  ]
};
```

I've tried changing the $map global variable in the FeatureSetByName function to the other global variables options ($datastore, $feature, $layer) but have had no luck.

Has anyone had any success creating a FeatureSet from a GeoJSON service? How did you declare it?

EDIT

Code can be found [here](https://codepen.io/WinkelTripel/pen/vYKQKaE?editors=1000)

Answer (score 0):

The methods to retrieve `FeatureSet` like `FeatureSetByName` only applies to `FeatureLayer` if I am not wrong. In that regard you will not be able to use `GeoJSONLayer`.

About `FeatureSetByName` in ArcGIS docs

> Creates a FeatureSet from a Feature Layer based on its name within a map or feature service.

[ArcGIS Arcade - FeatureSetByName](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/data_functions/#featuresetbyname)

You can try to create the `FeatureSet`, the constructor takes as an argument a GeoJSON. Then use this `FeatureSet` in the script.

[ArcGIS Arcade - FeatureSet type](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/guide/types/#featureset)

[ArcGIS Arcade - FeatureSet function](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/data_functions/#featureset)

Another option would be to retrieve the GeoJSON and use it to create a `FeatureLayer`.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look into this. With this being a hosted GeoJSON file from the web, it doesn't match the typical format that the documentation you linked describes. Any idea how to make this work with a hosted GeoJSON? I've linked my code in the original post if that would help.